# Concatenated Variable Name in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

This problem is not as straightforward as I thought, I am trying to define the name of the variable as a mixture of `report` and the actual value of the variable `numClicks`.

report1, report2, report3, report4, etc...

```
<?

<script>
var numClicks = 0
</script>  

echo "<img  height =\"16\"  src = \"images/stapler.png\"  

        onclick=\"
        numClicks++;
        var report+numClicks = '".$reports[$i]."';
        return confirm(report+numClicks);

    \">
"
?>
```

Is it possible to declare and define a variable like this in JavaScript, or do they have to be predefined before the page is loaded?

---

`$reports[$i]` is a variable whose value is the name of the report.

What I would like to do is to enable the user to batch several reports together, then send that information to MySQL.

Comment: There are ways to do dynamic variable names in JS, but I don't think that's what you need here. Why not just use an array?

Comment: Learn to use single and double quotes properly, it'll greatly help with your PHP code readability.  I'm submitting an edit to your code now to fix it

Comment: `echo`ing HTML like this makes it more difficult to read and write it. Just echo `$reports[$i]` only.

Comment: Note you could use double quotes and PHP's variable replacement (have a look at how PHP will insert variable values into double quoted strings) but getting rid of all the escaped double quotes is cleaner in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way.  Perhaps if you show us more what you're really trying to accomplish, we can help you figure out how to do it.

Local variable names must be known at the time you write the code:

```
var myVariableName;
```

`myVariableName` is an identifier, not a javascript expression.

You can create global variables from an expression because global variables are really just properties of the window object.  So, you could declare a global variable like this:

```
window["report"+numClicks] = "foo";
```

You can also create arrays or objects of your own and assign values in the array or properties on the object using an expression as the key or index.

```
var reportArray = [];              // declare array
reportArray[numClicks] = "foo";    // assign array entry
```

Or, you could use an object:

```
var reports = {};
reports[numClicks] = "foo";         // assign object property
```

In your particular code example, I don't quite follow what you're trying to do (I don't read PHP very well if that's what this is).  But, I think it could all be changed to:

```
onclick="return(confirm('".$reports[$i]."'))"
```

or something like that (you might have to fix the server-side part of it).  You don't need any local variables to do that.

Comment: @Felix King - I corrected it to use the term `identifier` - that is what I meant.

Comment: I like this. Going with it for a bit.

Comment: You don't need to use the global/window object, you can use a local object.

Comment: @RobG - a local object or a local array are both in my answer as examples as is a solution that doesn't need any local variables.

Answer (score 1):

If `report` is an object you can do:

```
var report = {};    
report['click'+ numClicks] = 'somestuff';
console.log(report.click1); // logs 'somestuff'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a cleaner way of passing variables between php and javascript

settings.php

```
<?php
    var settings = new array(
        "name" => "foo",
        "age" => "bar",
    );
    $json = json_encode(settings);
    echo "var global_settings ={$json};"
?>
```

html/js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(global_settings.name);
    alert(global_settings.age);
</script>
```